# Dynamic filenames

Tags: python, filenames

So I'm working on a program where I store data into multiple .txt files. The naming convention I want to use is file"xx" where the Xs are numbers, so file00, file01, ... all the way up to file20, and I want the variables assigned to them to be fxx (f00, f01, ...).

How would I access these files in Python using a for loop (or anther method), so I don't have to type out `open("fileXX")` 21 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of writing `t` to all files:

```
for x in range(22): #Remember that the range function returns integers up to 22-1
    exec "f%02d = open('file%02d.txt', 'w')" % (x, x)
```

I use the `exec` statement but there's probably a better way. I hope you get the idea though.

**NOTE:** This method will give you the variable names `fXX` to work with later if needed. The last two lines are just examples. Not really needed if all you need is to assign `fileXX.txt` to `fXX`.

**EDIT:** Removed the other last two lines because it seemed that people just weren't too happy with me putting them there. *Explanations for downvotes are always nice.*

Comment: Why would you use `exec`? You can just reuse the variable storing the file handle, so there's no need to make ones with different names - the only interpolation you need to do is in the filename: `f = open('file%02d.txt' % x, 'w')`.

Comment: Because the OP might need those variables in that format later as he says: *"i want the variables assigned to them to be fxx (f00,f01...)"*. Using just `f =` won't allow him to have those variable names. `exec` allows him to have the variable names he needs

Comment: Well I said there's probably a better way than to use `exec` but this method does allow him to have what he wants, no?

Comment: Well, yes, you're right in that it works but wrong in that `exec` is not the right tool here. I didn't downvote you, by the way.

Comment: No worries, I could tell you didn't :P.

Comment: yah, it works thanks guys. i know that some might think it's bad style, but i just need to get this done :P

Answer (score 5):

The names are regular. You can create the list of filenames with a simple list comprehension.

```
["f%02d"%x for x in range(1,21)]
```

Comment: For more details on string interpolation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 1):

Look into python's [glob module](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

It uses the usual shell wildcard syntax, so `??` would match any two characters, while `*` would match anything.  You could use either `f??.txt` or `f*.txt`, but the former is a more strict match, and wouldn't match something like `fact_or_fiction.txt` while the latter would.

E.g.:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.iglob('f??.txt'):
    infile = file(filename)
    # Do stuff...
```

Comment: `glob` is a great option. If, however, you only wanted to access a certain set (say, f0-99 existed, but you only wanted f0-19), then you could use string interpolation: `"f%02d" % 4` becomes `"f04"`.

Comment: +1 to Amber. I would use glob only if I wanted all files matching a pattern. For a series of files whose names are known a priori, I would generate the names.

Comment: If you need a reference for interpolation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: @Amber - True, and it's worth noting that glob won't necessarily return things in sorted order (it depends on the underlying filesystem).

Comment: But `sorted()` can be used to fix the latter.

Comment: in addition, glob will only return you **existing** matching files, which does not help you if you want to **create** them as the original poster does (and they did not exist before)

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is the OP wants to register the variables programagically:

```
for i in range( 20 ):
    locals()[ "f%02d" % i ] = open( "file%02d.txt" % i )
```

and then e.g.

```
print( f01 )
...
```

Comment: @vlad003 - http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces  Also, looking up a global variable is slower than looking up a local variable, so beyond the usual avoidance of global variables, there's a speed difference, as well.

Comment: @vlad003: I never said it was better than `globals()` (it is equivalent to `vars()` with no arguments), I said that it was better than `exec`. However, Joe is right in that it *is* better.

Comment: Anything's probably better than `exec`; I only put it here b/c it *works, even though not the best*.
@Joe: thanks for the link. I never read the tutorial. I usually learn by doing so I learn as I go.

Comment: This'd work but I don't like the idea of magically creating variables in my namespace. I'd much prefer that these names were put into a dictionary or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = [open("file%02d", "w") for x in xrange(0, 20+1)]
# now use files[0] to files[20], or loop

# example: write number to each file
for n, f in enumerate(files):
  files.write("%d\n" % n)

# reopen for next example
files = [open("file%02d", "r") for x in xrange(0, 20+1)]
# example: print first line of each file
for n, f in enumerate(files):
  print "%d: %s" % (n, f.readline())
```